# Message Counter for specific words discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to build a message counter for discord.py that counts specific messages and then responds with the number of times the message was said in that day.

I have the base but I  don't know how to build the actual counter... Here is my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.utils

class Message_Counter(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, ctx, message):


        if "oof" in message.content:
            await ctx.send(str(counter))
        elif "Thot" in message.content:
            await ctx.send(str(counter))

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Message_Counter(client))
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm using the rewrite branch of discord.py if that helps.

Basically for Thot it would respond with `**Thot counter**: <number>`

For oof it would respond with `**oof counter**: <number>`

so on so forth.

I would also like it to reset the counter on a daily basis so that around every 24 hours the counter starts over.

Comment: Do you restart your bot on a regular basis? If yes, then I would use a json file you read and write from.

Comment: How would I code this to work through a json file? I still don't have the actual counter in there. So honestly that's my biggest issue in this one.

But yes, a json file system is what I use so that would work in my favor.

Answer (score 1):

**Using json** (quick introduction to JSON [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp))

We want to create a json file with name `counters.json` in the same folder as the file(s) for your bot. Its contents should look like this:

```
{
    "Thot": 0,
    "oof": 0
}
```

Loading a json file into a [dictionary](http://introtopython.org/dictionaries.html) works with the json library:
(If you have no idea what the "with open" stuff is about, [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python/) is a primer on file reading and writing operations)

```py
import json

def load_counters():
    with open('counters.json', 'r') as f:
       counters = json.load(f)
    return counters
```

Saving the dictionary back to json works in a very similar vein:

```py
def save_counters(counters):
    with open('counters.json', 'w') as f:
       json.dump(counters, f)
```

Now that we have a way of loading and unloading our counters from json, we can change the bot code to use them:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.utils

class Message_Counter(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, ctx, message):
        if "oof" in message.content:
            counters = load_counters()
            counters["oof"] += 1
            await ctx.send(str(counters["oof"]))
            save_counters(counters)
        elif "Thot" in message.content:
            counters = load_counters()
            counters["Thot"] += 1
            await ctx.send(str(counters["Thot"]))
            save_counters(counters)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Message_Counter(client))
```

Comment: This keeps throwing an error. I had this same problem when using json storage to run a set prefix command from inside a cog... i reeally don't wan to have another command outside my cogs... here is the error it keeps throwing...
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joshu\PycharmProjects\Discord_Bots\Ranma\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'```

Comment: @Nimbi That is a completely different problem to the one you posted. It is an easy fix, but please post another question about it, as it is a bit hard to answer in a comment.

Comment: Alright new question posted... Here is the link.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62566015/issue-when-running-some-commands-from-within-cogs-discord-py